# Oracle query to convert to UTC time

Tags: oracle, datetime, utc

I need to convert a date value to it's corresponding UTC timestamp. I found below sql through google. Please advise me if I have any risk in using this sql. Will this work during daylight saving time of my oracle server as well? Do we have any daylight saving in UTC zone as well? Please advise me.

```
SQL> Select Sys_extract_UTC(systimestamp) from dual;

SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12-JUN-13 10.21.27.882563 AM
```

Comment: How do you know that the solution proposed here won't be *risky* as well?